# Test if a systemd unit is active in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, admin, systemd

I'm writing a script to automatically install a bind server on a CentOs 7 distribution.

I'm stuck with `systemctl status`, because it does not produce an error code (it's right, since a status is not an error) I can use.

What I want is to check whether the service is started (active). What is the best and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Actually `systemctl status` does return a status - as I found when doing `systemctl status openvpn@<>`. Where the values are `0` for running, and `3` for stopped. However, this command is interactive :(. Hence the @lars suggested  `systemctl is-active` is the way to go, and better att the `-q` as suggested by @palswim

Answer (score 44):

The best way to check if a service is active is with the `systemctl is-active` command:

```
# systemctl start sshd
# systemctl is-active sshd >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo YES || echo NO
YES
# systemctl stop sshd
# systemctl is-active sshd >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo YES || echo NO
NO
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for! it seems i missed it in the manual. ^^'

Comment: You can also use the `-q` switch so that you don't have to redirect output: `systemctl -q is-active sshd`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to check in a shell script, you can do:

```
if (systemctl -q is-active some_application.service)
    then
    echo "Application is still running."
    exit 1
fi
```

To check if a application is not running just add a exclamation mark in the condition.

Comment: This if statement always resolved to true because the strings "active" and "inactive" are both true.

Comment: The script works fine in my production machines. If an application is running the script exits, else it continues the script.

Comment: looks like the script is checking the return code of systemctl not the string returned.  So it works.

Comment: "This if statement always resolved to true because the strings "active" and "inactive" are both true." -> I tested and it worked for me.

Comment: For the pair with `-q` flag it's better to check explicitly for status code.
e.g.
`
systemctl -q is-active some_application.service\n
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then\n
  echo 'App running'\n
  exit 0\n
fi
`
p.s. sorry for the mess with code block, it's impossibru to use newline for comments.